# Example of complex projective variety without a real descent

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I encountered the problem of trying to find the examples of complex varieties which are not the complexification of a real variety, when I considered the Exercise II.4.7.(a) in Hartshorne's book. I wonder whether there are indeed some interesting complex varieties which don't have the so called semi-linear involution in Hartshorne's book.

For rational affine curve, I have found the following example $$A=\mathbb{C}[x,\frac{1}{x-1},\frac{1}{x-i},\frac{1}{x-i-1}]$$
    by a little hard calculation, considering the possible semi-linear involutions of the field $\mathbb{C}\left(x\right)$ induced by the complex conjugation of $\mathbb{C}$ .

But I really wonder

> whether there are some interesting examples of complex projective varieties without real descent.

I have poor knowledge on the classical topics in algebraic geometry, therefore I find it difficult to work out the problem by myself. Could anyone shed some light on my confusion? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If $X$ is a complex algebraic variety with a model over $\mathbb{R}$, then $X$ is isomorphic over $\mathbb{C}$ to its conjugate $X^{\sigma}$. (Here, $\sigma:Spec \mathbb{C}\to Spec \mathbb{C}$ is complex conjugation, and $X^{\sigma} = X\times_{\mathbb{C},\sigma}\mathbb{C}$.) So, "interesting" examples of complex algebraic varieties which can't be defined over $\mathbb{R}$ can be constructed by simply writing down objects which aren't isomorphic to their conjugate. For instance, let $E$ be an elliptic curve with $j$-invariant $j(E)$...cont'd

Comment: ...Suppose that $\overline{j(E)}\neq j(E)$. Now, since $j(E^{\sigma}) = \overline{j(E})$, it follows that $E$ and $E^{\sigma}$ are not isomorphic. For an explicit example: take $E$ to be an elliptic curve with $j$-invariant equal to $\sqrt{-1}$. This elliptic curve can't be defined over $\mathbb{R}$. You can find higher genus curves by using instead of elliptic curves higher genus hyperelliptic curves.

Comment: This is indeed a nice illustration for my confusion. I think I will understand the problem better after learning some about elliptic curves. Thanks lot!